# All but belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I want to get all rows, that is opposite of `belongsToMany` relationship on Laravel.

For example, there is `events` table and `visits` table. If a user has visited an event, then visited on pivot `event_visit` table is marked 1.

I want to get all those events, that **are not** visited.

For example, User model:

```
public function userVisitedEvents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Visits::class, 'event_visit')
        ->where('visited', '=', '1');
}//end userVisitedEvents()
```

This selects **all** visited events.

**What I want to achieve:** I need to get **the opposite**, get all events, that are either:

1. marked as visited 0
2. this visit is not stored at all (there are no relation)

The problem is there because `belongsToMany` relation is created using `INNER JOIN`. If it would be created with `LEFT JOIN` - no problem.

PS - `->where('visited', '<>', '1');` won't work, because it would find only (1) case, not all events.

Maybe there is a chance to tell which join to use?
Or the only option would be to use query builder by hand?

Comment: It's not a concern of the user to fetch all non visited events. You need to provide that using a query scope from the Visit model

Comment: A solution that might not be pretty would be to do that select, and save the id's , then do another one doing the oposite,( getting event from visit)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for "Relationship Absence"

```
$events = Event::doesntHave('userVisitedEvents')->get();
```

You may have to adapt it to your context. If you can't work with it, also check

```
Event::whereDoesntHave(...); //takes a closure.
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Seems like I've missed this in documentation. Seems to be working. I gonna try this, will give report, how did it go!